# How do I search youtube instead of using a url in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to creating a discord music bot and am trying to implement a play command. I want my play command to work for both urls and to search youtube. So far urls work, but I can not get the search to work.

Here is my code:

```
@commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def play(self, ctx, *, info):
        try:
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel # checks if user is in voice channel
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            VOICE_CHANNELS[channel.id] = ctx.channel
        except AttributeError:
            return await ctx.send("Dush! Please Join a Channel.") # user is not in a voice channel

        voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
        if not voice_client:
            await voice_channel.connect()
            voice_client = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        try:
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(info, download=False)) 
            title = data["title"] # get title
            song = data["url"] # get url
            if "entries" in data: # checks for playlist 
                    data = data["entries"][0] # if its a playlist, we get the first item
        except Exception as e:
            data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info("ytsearch:" + info, download=False))
            song = data["formats"][0]["url"]
            title = data["formats"][0]["title"]
            if 'entries' in data:
                    data = data['entries'][0]
            
        try:
            voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=song,**ffmpeg_options, executable="ffmpeg")) #playing the audio
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {title}')
```

It gives this error when I try to put anything thats not a url.

```
2023-04-16 19:36:42 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Joey\Documents\CIS1051-final-project\JoyBot\cogs\Commands.py", line 98, in play
    song = data["url"] # get url
           ~~~~^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'url'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Joey\Documents\CIS1051-final-project\JoyBot\cogs\Commands.py", line 103, in play
    song = data["formats"][0]["url"]
           ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'formats'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'formats'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is happening with your search function?    Please include details as to what happens when you run it.  What is the expected output?  What is the actual output?  What did you try to search?

Comment: Sorry im still new to this. I edited it.

Comment: Are you sure ```data``` has the ```url``` key?  What does ```data``` look like?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. Im using ytdl to extract info and storing it in data.